# Oracle: Error importing DB dump using impdp: Data Pump client is incompatible with database version 12.1.0.2.0

Tags: oracle, impdp

We created a DB dump from an Oracle DB v12.**1** using the expdp (export data pump) v12.1 utility and I now want to import it into an other DB v12.**1** using the impdp (import data pump) tool. For misc. reasons I need to do this from a third system (i.e. I can not do this locally on the second system).

For this I am using an "InstantClient" v12.**2** (because that's the first/oldest downloadable InstantClient version that also contains the impdp and expdp utility). According to some compatibility table that I found this should be possible and a valid combination.
However, when I start the impdp utility I always only get a "UDI-0018 Data Pump client is incompatible with database version 12.1.0.2.0" error message.
Below is my complete console output (of course `<usr>` and `<pwd>` contain actual values...):

```
...
ORACLE_SID: mdbprod
ORACLE_BASE: /opt/oracle
ORACLE_HOME: /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2
TNS_ADMIN: /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2/network/admin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2:/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib:/lib:/usr/lib
PATH: /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2:/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games
executing: impdp <user>/<pwd>@mdbprod DIRECTORY=IMPDP_INBOX LOGFILE=IMPDP_LOGS:impdp.log DUMPFILE=expdp_02.dmp,expdp_04.dmp,expdp_01.dmp,expdp_dmp SCHEMAS=ZHQUEST REMAP_SCHEMA=ZHQUEST:ZHQUESTMIG_2 REMAP_TABLESPACE=DATEN_ZHQUEST:ZHQUESTMIG_2_DATEN TRANSFORM=segment_attributes:n TRANSFORM=disable_archive_logging:y TRANSFORM=oid:n EXCLUDE=user EXCLUDE=tablespace_quota,system_grant,INDEX_STATISTICS EXCLUDE=TABLE:"=\'PLAN_TABLE\'" EXCLUDE=TABLE:"LIKE \'BATCH_JOB%\'",TABLE:"LIKE \'BATCH_STEP%\'" EXCLUDE=TABLE:"=\'XML_MELDUNG_QUEUE\'" TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=replace PARALLEL=16

Import: Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on Thu Sep 5 17:33:38 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
UDI-00018: Data Pump client is incompatible with database version 12.1.0.2.0

++ warning ++ : [import_dumps_zhquest_into_ZHQUESTMIG_2.sh] Unexpected result [1]
```

...

Any idea anyone, why this combination is not working? What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Where did you see that a 12.2 client is compatible with a 12.1 DB? Have a look at [MoS Doc ID 553337.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=553337.1), particularly section 4.1, which says that it is not. (Also slightly confused that you have to use a third system - the dump file has to be on the target DB server anyway?)

Comment: You  can download the 12.1 client from here: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/database12c-win64-downloads.html

Comment: @Alex Poole: thanks for the comment. Unfortunately following that link requires some Oracle "Support Identifier" which I don't have. And re. your confusion: we create the dump on one system, transfer them to the third and want to "pump" it from there remotely into the second.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: unfortunately this is the download for Windows. Do you by chance have the corresponding download URL for Linux? We are on Suse here and I couldn't find any link on that page pointing to other versions or such.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: nevermind - I found the corresponding Linux download page, but can one somehow figure out - without actually installing the package - whether the client package contains the impdp and expdp tools? If not I would have to download and install the "full" DB (which is an almost 3GB download :-( )

Comment: The full (not instant) client *does* include those tools. The dump file has to be on the target (second) system, or at least visible to it e.g. via an NFS mount. I'd verify that is the case before spending time installing the client.

Comment: Then check this one: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/oracle-database-software-downloads.html Click on "View all" then you can download also Oracle Clients (not only Database server)

Comment: Thanks both - you got me going. Client is working. That restriction re. dumps to be imported having to be local to the DB is a major issue, though, and will require some discussion re. the future workflow. Thanks for making me aware!